# Trying to edit data with fetch put but cannot refer to proper id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am basically trying to edit an already entered data witch fetch & put. The problem is that i cannot refer to proper id with this code:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import NewMeetupForm from "../components/meetups/NewMeetupForm";

function EditForm(props) {
  const history = useHistory();

  function addMeetupHandler(meetupData) {
    fetch(
      `https://reacttesty-2fbdf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/api/book/${props.id}.json`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(meetupData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    ).then(() => {
      history.replace("/");
    });
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Add New Meetupes</h1>
      <NewMeetupForm onAddMeetup={addMeetupHandler} />
    </section>
  );
}

export default EditForm;
```

On already existing object i have a Link:

```
<Link to={`/edit-meetup`}>
          <button>Edit</button>
        </Link>
```

Which directs me to the same form in which i add a new elements, and i think that there i lost my id on which i want to make edits

What this code does is just creating a new object with  `undefined` id.
I thought that giving it a `props.id` will just simply works because i did it with `DELETE` method  where it was fine and I thought I will achieve same result with PUT method but it aint that simple. If anyone could help that would be greate. I dont really know much about fetch, im learning react but i have to refer to some  dummy API.

Comment: The code & etc works fine becuase i tried to edit the data on object with undefined id and it changes.

Comment: Yes it does, the EditForm is the code which i posted here and NewMeetupForm is a Form in which i add data and im trying to use it also as an editor to already existing objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow Community.

Follow the below-mentioned steps to fix your problem.

1. Update the relevant Route like this in App.js or where ever application routes defined component.

```js
<Route path="/edit-meetup/:id"> {/* Get your id */}
  <EditForm />
</Route>
```

2. Then access to that id in your `EditForm` component like this.

```js
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import NewMeetupForm from "../components/meetups/NewMeetupForm";

function EditForm(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { id } = useParams(); // Access to your id 

  const addMeetupHandler = (meetupData) => {
    fetch(
      `https://reacttesty-2fbdf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/api/book/${id}.json`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(meetupData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    ).then(() => {
      history.replace("/");
    });
  }; // It's better if you can use an arrow function here

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Add New Meetupes</h1>
      <NewMeetupForm onAddMeetup={addMeetupHandler} />
    </section>
  );
}

export default EditForm;
```

3. Pass *id* to the `Link` also.

```js
<Link to={`/edit-meetup/${id}`}>
  <button>Edit</button>
</Link>;
```

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, but i felt bad that i didn't figure it out myself ;p. Have a nice day